# Shell script is not helping to kill tomcat application

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I've to replicate behaviour of `CTRL+C` using shell script to turned down tomcat application server. Hence wrote following code in Jenkins pipeline script -

```
sh '''pgrep -fl catalina | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT'''
```

But it does not turn application down. However if I executed same command from terminal, it turns down the application -

```
pgrep -fl catalina | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT
```

Can you please help to understand what is wrong with shell script code?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$`? You can see that it works when you don't. Run it that way.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. `$` need not to be escaped. And run it with that but still server did not go down.

Comment: The `$` would need to be escaped as its otherwise unquoted. I think Nasir didn't see that the whole pipeline was quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The two commands are not the same.  The first command tries to run a script called, literally, `pgrep -fl catalina | awk {print` with the argument `} | xargs kill -SIGINT` (assuming `$1` is empty in the calling shell).  It should give you a "No such file or directory" error.  It does this due to the quoting.

Triple single quotes in the shell is just an awkward way of starting an ordinary single quote (the first two single quotes would be an empty string).  And a single quoted string *can not* contain a single quote. This means that `{print $1}` is unquoted in your command, so the shell expands the `$1` (probably to nothing), and then splits the command on that space after `print`.

To run the pipeline with `sh`, use `sh -c`:

```
sh -c 'sh pgrep -fl catalina | awk "{ print \$1 }" | xargs kill -SIGINT'
```

Or, just use `pkill`:

```
pkill -f -SIGINT catalina
```

Or, [you could use](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/9780596101060/ch01s02.html) the `shutdown.sh` script for Tomcat, or `catalina.sh stop`, or `service tomcat stop`.

Comment: `pkill -f -SIGINT catalina` through shell script does not turn server down and `sh -c 'sh pgrep -fl catalina | awk "{ print \$1 }" | xargs kill -SIGINT'`
 giver compilation error - `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2619: expecting '}', found 'sh pgrep -fl catalina | awk "{ print $1 }" | xargs kill -SIGINT' @ line 2619, column 47.
                           sh -c 'sh pgrep `

Comment: `pkill -9 -f tomcat`, `sh ./shutdown.sh` and `sh ./catalina.sh stop' are not helping to achieve what `CTRL+C` does. hence opted for `kill -SIGINT`

Comment: @TDHM Why do you put `sh` in front  of `shutdown.sh` etc.? Also, have you tried `service tomcat stop` or similar commands (`systemctl`?) to stop the service?

Comment: Yes `sh` is not needed actually. `systemctl` asks for login details which makes things complicated in shell script(based on my knoweldge)

Answer (score 0):

well, to begin with, you're making things unnecessarily complex.

It looks like you want to match the full command name 'catalina'.  If that's the case, then I think you want to use the '-x' parameter. and, if you don't use the '-l', then you won't get a command name that then needs to be cut out with 'awk'.

```
pgrep -x catalina
```

You can then interpolate the 'pgrep' command into the 'kill' command line.

```
sh 'kill -SIGINT `pgrep -x catalina` '
```

even better yet:

```
killall  -SIGINT --exact catalina
```

As to why this works in one context and not in the other, it's not clear.  Perhaps you're running as a different (non-root) user  in the Jenkins Pipeline context and the correct (or root) user when you are in the terminal?